# How to created named list from pmap over set of parameters

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following parameter set and a function that takes the value from params

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
params <- tribble(
  ~mean, ~sd, ~n, ~chosen_name, 
  5, 1, 1, "Param1", 
  10, 5, 3, "Param2"
)

my_norm_func  <- function(mean, sd, n, chosen_name) {
  rnorm(mean, sd, n) 
}
```

When executing it the following way using **[pmap](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html)**:

```
params %>% 
  pmap(my_norm_func)
```

I get this result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.3735462 1.1836433 0.1643714 2.5952808 1.3295078

[[2]]
 [1]  2.538595  6.462287  7.214974  6.727344  4.083835  9.535344  6.169530  3.136278 -1.644100  8.374793
```

What I want to get is a named list based on `chosen_name` column in `params`:

```
$Param1
[1] 0.3735462 1.1836433 0.1643714 2.5952808 1.3295078

$Param2
 [1]  2.538595  6.462287  7.214974  6.727344  4.083835  9.535344  6.169530  3.136278 -1.644100  8.374793
```

What should I do to achieve that? Be it modifying the function or pmap call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set_names` at the end is an option

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
params %>% 
   pmap(my_norm_func) %>% 
   set_names(params$chosen_name)
```

---

Or another option is `deframe`

```
library(tibble)
params %>% 
    transmute(newcol = pmap(., my_norm_func), chosen_name) %>% 
    select(chosen_name, newcol) %>% 
    deframe
#$Param1
#[1] -0.9143594  2.1765833 -0.6649724  0.5364696 -0.1159201

#$Param2
# [1]  2.7475430 11.2614996  5.0521869  1.1410984  0.0781834  6.3505613  4.9443205  4.0457949  2.2119136  0.5376191
```

---

Or another approach is to modify the function by outputing as a `list` with naming the list element with 'chosen_name`and then`flatten`the`list`

```
my_norm_func  <- function(mean, sd, n, chosen_name) {
   list(rnorm(mean, sd, n)) %>%
      set_names(chosen_name)
   }

params %>%
   pmap(my_norm_func) %>%
   flatten
#$Param1
#[1] 3.3079784 1.1058024 1.4569988 0.9228471 0.6659992

#$Param2
# [1]  4.8958219  7.3629188 11.2257350  8.0821773  8.6237252  1.3060297  7.9516867  5.6597744  0.5982499  6.5630682
```

Comment: I want the names to be called from `chosen_name` in the `params` df. Coz the name can be anything in my actual case.

Comment: @scamander  If it is coming from the data, then change that to `params$chosen_name`